# R shiny: renderPlot duplicates values, ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, reactive

I have an issue with a reactive ggplot in Shiny.

necessary packages

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
```

generate a dataset, it contains non-valid names, and the corresponding valid Name

```
df_pheno<- data.frame(Species = sample(c("Euthycerina pilosa", "Euthycerina pilosa", "Euthycerina pilosa", "Euthycerina vittithorax", "Euthycerina test")),
Number = sample(c("3", "4", "1", "1", "2")),
Date = sample(c("1", "50", "2", "30", "1")))

df_pheno$Number <- as.numeric(as.character(df_pheno$Number))
df_pheno$Date <- as.numeric(as.character(df_pheno$Date))
```

simple ui

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput('validSpecies', 'Choose species', 
                     choices = df_pheno$Species, 
                     options = list(placeholder = 'select species'))
    ),   
    mainPanel(plotOutput("pheno")           
    )
  )
)
```

a server that generates reactive plot

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
output$pheno <- renderPlot({
ggplot(df_pheno, aes(x=Date, y= Species == input$validSpecies, fill = Number)) + geom_tile(color="white", size=0.1)+ 
scale_fill_gradient(low="light grey", high="red", name="# specimens", breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,5), labels=c(0,1,2,3,4,">=5"), limits=c(0,5))+   scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52), labels=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52), limits=c(0,53))  + 
coord_equal()+ 
labs(x=NULL, y=NULL, title="Phenology of this species, per week")+
theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))+ 
theme(axis.ticks=element_blank())+ 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=7, angle=60)) + 
theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=7, face = "italic")) + 
theme(legend.title=element_text(size=8)) + 
theme(legend.text=element_text(size=8))    
  })
}
```

and run it

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

So what do I want: if you select a certain species in the selectizeInput, you generate a plot with the data of ONLY that specific species.

what is this script doing: if you select a certain species in selectizeInput, it shows you a (very good) plot with two species?!

I do not see my error, although, it is probably quite logic.

Thanks for all your help,
Best wishes,
Jonas

Comment: Your example doesn't include any data for `df_pheno$Number`

Comment: Hi Jared, 
I do not know why I omitted that one, now corrected :-)
Rest of the script is OK now - still the same problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in your server function, in `ggplot`, you should replace this part

```
ggplot(df_pheno, aes(x=Date, y= Species == input$validSpecies, fill = Number))
```

with this

```
ggplot(data = df_pheno[df_pheno$Species == input$validSpecies,], 
       aes(x = Date, y = Species, fill = Number))
```

That is, you should subset the data and not the variable that you map into y.

Also, consider to replace the long sequence: `c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52)` with `1:52`.